# Qr code scanner PostgreSQL Database Validation

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a very basic qr code scanner entrance database system with postgresql

2 tables:

Table "persons" include a list of all participants with: id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, qr_code
Table "check_ins" include a list of all the people who entered the event: id, person_id, check_in_time

I created this query:

```
INSERT INTO check_ins (person_id)
SELECT id
FROM persons
WHERE qr_code = {{ scanner1.data[0]}} AND
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM persons WHERE qr_code = {{ scanner1.data['0']}})
```

{{ scanner1.data[0]}} is the scanner input value

The query still work for qr_code that aren't present in table persons. I'm expecting an error (I have a popup that trigger if the query is a failure with a text "Qr Code Already scanned or Invalid")

I'm expecting this:
qr_code scanned present in table persons but not in table check_ins = insert in table check_ins | query run successfully
qr_code scanned not present in table persons = query failure
qr_code scanned present in table persons but also in table check_ins = query failure

I structured the app so when the query run successfully a text will appear with "Qr code valid" and when not "Qr code already scanned or invalid"

Answer (score 0):

This query returns either the `id` of the new `check_ins` record or an empty resultset (nothing was inserted because either `t` CTE had no record in it or this `person_id` already existed in `check_ins`).
So you can distinguish success from failure by the result.

```sql
with t(pid) as 
(
 SELECT id FROM persons
 WHERE qr_code = {{ scanner1.data['0']}}
)
INSERT INTO check_ins (person_id)
 SELECT pid from t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM check_ins WHERE person_id = t.pid)
RETURNING id;
```